# UTF-8 encoding problem in unix machine

Tags: java, unix, tomcat, utf-8

Im exporting a set of data to excel in java, the data has certain non ascii characters, while exporting in Windows machine the data are coming correctly in UTF-8 encoded format.But when i deploy my code in Unix machine it is not working properly.UTF-8 encoding is not working properly.
Im using Tomcat 5.5 server.I have also included URIencoding="UTF_8"  parameter in server.xml. But still in unix machine it is not working properly

Comment: Yeah, please show some example data and tell us what happens exactly.

Comment: from Database im exporting set of data into a csv file using java. In windows the exported data are coming correctly in UTF-8 encoding.The abnormal characters are not coming in windows.but when i deploy it in unix machine and then export my data in to a csv file, abnormal characters are coming i.e it is not coming in UTF-8 format.Im using tomcat server.

Comment: From where is the problematic data coming from? HTTP request? Text file? Database? Each of those options can have issues and solutions are different in all the cases. I have a feeling that your issue might be the database, so it would be helpful to mention: what database server are you using, how do you connect to it (connection parameters), do you use exactly the same JDBC library to connect from Unix and from Windows?

Comment: the data are from database. im using mysql server connection. ya using the same JDBC library only.

Comment: "abnormal characters are coming i.e it is not coming in UTF-8 format" Are you sure the abnormal characters aren't there *because* it is in UTF-8 and your viewer isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Running Tomcat with a

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

option will force the VM to adopt UTF8 as it's default encoding regardless of your environment. I suspect that's your problem (and it's good practise nonetheless)

Comment: I tried -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 option in CATALINA_OPTS in tomcat start shell script. But still its not working.Please help me in this.

Comment: It is coming fine in UI but when i export the data only it is not coming in UTF format in UNIX. please help me

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with UTF-8 data it can be very fragile.  Every step in the chain needs to specify utf8.

(1) In the database, be sure the table has UTF8 encoding and collation.  "show table status" will tell you this.  Google for "mysql alter table utf8" for more info.

(2) The JDBC connection needs to specify the UTF8 encoding.  For Connector/J this will be something similar to:

```
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

(3) Every stream read/write, every string to byte conversion in the code needs to specify UTF-8 as the encoding.  It's easy to miss one.  If it's missed Java will use the system default which will vary server to server.

(4) Not applicable here, but for user submitted data from a form, you need to set the request character encoding.  (I do this in a servlet filter)

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

(5) Probably not applicable here, but if you output HTML/XML/text from your servlet, set the HTTP character encoding header.  (This might apply if you are generating the Excel file as an XML file).

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```